# how fetchall sqlite3 data into pretytable printing in python

Tags: python, sqlite, mod-python

i am new in python so far i need help for this output from sqlite3

```
(u'GABRIELLA TEGGIA (40)', u'-', u'65')
(u'PUTRA', u'DPS', u'11')
(u'SUASTINI', u'-', u'-')
(u'ARI UTAMA', u'JL.D.BERATAN GG.8/4', u'26')
(u'SUYASA', u'DS.TUNJUK,TABANAN', u'33')
(u'SARAH(41)', u'BEJI AYU', u'40')
(u'AA.GDE OKA', u'JL.H.WURUK 179 DPS', u'53')
(u'AYU NILA RADIASTUTI', u'ABIAN BASE,KAPAL', u'8')
(u'DANTI I NYOMAN', u'GIANYAR', u'50')
(u'INDAYANI', u'BUNUTIN,UBUD', u'6')
(u'JENNI', u'JL.MUTIARA NO.18 KEROBOKAN', u'37')
(u'JERRY G.J ABELL', u'HOLLAND', u'-')
(u'COK ALIT', u'BR.MUKTI,SINGAPADU', u'35')
(u'SUPARTI NI PUTU', u'KARANGASEM', u'51')
(u'SUMADA I GD', u'SINGARAJA', u'60')
```

but i can only fetch only the last row like this one

```
+-------------+-----------+------+
|    Pasien   |   Alamat  | Umur |
+-------------+-----------+------+
| SUMADA I GD | SINGARAJA |  60  |
+-------------+-----------+------+
```

how to get the complete rows to print? 
I provide with my code here:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db3')
cursor=connection.cursor()
print("Show data row by row:")
print('-'*40)

from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
x.set_field_names(["Pasien", "Alamat", "Umur"])

cursor.execute('SELECT nm_pasien, almt_pasien, umur_pasien from pasien limit 15')


for nm_pasien in cursor:
    print nm_pasien

print('-'*40)

x.add_row(nm_pasien)
x.printt()
```

I am using python 2.5 and pretytable module from [here](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/)

i am stuck please help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the `x.add_row`  call inside the for-loop:

```
for nm_pasien in cursor:        
    x.add_row(nm_pasien)
    # print nm_pasien
```

In your orginial code, with `x.add_row(nm_pasien)` outside the loop, `add_row` is only called once. Moreover, `nm_pasien` retains its last value from the for-loop. This is why you only see the last row of data printed in the PrettyTable.

Comment: Unfortunately after modify into this  `for nm_pasien in cursor:
    x.add_row(nm_pasien)
    x.printt()` i got the result `+-----------------------+--------+------+
|         Pasien        | Alamat | Umur |
+-----------------------+--------+------+
| GABRIELLA TEGGIA (40) |   -    |  65  |
+-----------------------+--------+------+
+-----------------------+--------+------+
|         Pasien        | Alamat | Umur |
+-----------------------+--------+------+
| GABRIELLA TEGGIA (40) |   -    |  65  |
+-----------------------+--------+------+
`only the first row repeated. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @kuslahne: What happens if you change `x.printt()` to `print(x)`? According to the tutorial http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial this should print the entire table.

Comment: Thanks @all, i got the solutions just by using [texttable](http://foutaise.org/code/texttable/) module. It generated the same result with showing all recordset.